# Norm and unit sphere

Tags: normed-spaces

I want to prove the following statement:

If the unit sphere in a normed space contains a segment, then there exists two vectors $x,y$ such that $\Vert x + y \Vert = \Vert x \Vert + \Vert y \Vert$ with $x$ and $y$ linearly independent.

This is what I have done:
Let $x$ and $y$ be the end point of the segment contained in the unit sphere. Then $\forall \lambda \in (0,1)$ I can write:

$$ \Vert \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \Vert \leq 1 $$ 
From here I am struggling on getting the relationship on $x+y$. Any pointers?

Comment: That looks wrong, even $\mathbb R$'s unit ball $[-1,1]$ contains a segment, but any two elements are dependent ... perhaps you want the unit *sphere* to contain a segment.

Comment: What a silly mistake, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ and $y$ the endpoints, as you write. Therefore we have 
$$ \|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\| = 1 $$ 
for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$. For $\lambda = \frac 12$, we have 
$$ \frac 12\|x+y\| = 1 \iff \|x+y\| = 2 = \|x\| + \|y\|. $$
If $x$ and $y$ were dependent, as both are element of the unit sphere, we would have $x = \mu y$ for some $|\mu| = 1$. Then 
$$ |\lambda \mu + (1-\lambda)| = 1 $$
for all $\lambda \in (0,1)$, which is impossible for $\mu \ne 1$.

Comment: The annoying nitpicker (me) points out that the reason that $\mu$ would exist if $x,y$ were dependent is not really because $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$ but because $y\ne 0$.......+1

Comment: It can also be easily seen that  this holds in complex as well as real spaces. For if $\mu\in \Bbb C$ with $|mu|=1$ and $|\lambda \mu +(1-\lambda)|=1$ for all $\lambda  \in (0,1)$, then  $\mu=1.$